# Append array element to FormData doesn't work in Firefox 15

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm making crossdomain ajax post request.
There is the client function:

```
function getUsersData()
{
  var ids = ["user1_id", "user2_id"];
  var fd = new FormData();
  $.each(ids, function() {
    fd.append('identities', this);
  });
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://some-domain.com/Home/GetUsersData', true);
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.onreadystatechange = responseHandler; //function is defined and not shown here
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Everything works fine in Opera and Google Chrome browsers.
But Firefox says **NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA: Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]** at the line *fd.append('identities', this);*

What it can be and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use unique keys. Something like: fd.append('identity-'+this.id, this);